# Is there a word for the material of a forest floor?

Tags: single-word-requests

I was in a forest last weekend and spent some time enjoying the texture of the forest floor - even now in the summer, it consists primarily of slowly decaying dry leaves and twigs:

[image: forestfloor]

I thought I had in the back of my mind a word for this substance, but I couldn't remember it. Now I think I might have been conflating the English word "loam" with the German word "Laub" which I think can mean this substance but also more generally means leaves/foliage.

Anyway, can anyone help me out? Do we have a word for it in English?

Sample usage: "the soft [Laub] rustled under her feet"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**litter**  (and more precisely   **leaf litter** )

In [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/litter)
we find this:

> **litter**
> 4.1  Decomposing but recognizable leaves and other debris forming a layer on top of the soil, especially in forests.
> *‘the spiders live in leaf litter’*

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plant_litter) seems to prefer **plant litter** or **litterfall**, but its article includes *plant litter*, *litterfall*, *leaf litter*, *tree litter*, *soil litter*, and *duff*. Having said that, Google Books Ngram Viewer ranks **leaf litter** at the top in terms of commonality, and it's also the most descriptive in terms of the picture in the question.

Comment: [The Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=plant+litter%2C+litterfall%2Cleaf+litter%2Ctree+litter%2Csoil+litter%2Cduff&corpus=26&year_end=2019&year_start=1800&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cplant%20litter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clitterfall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleaf%20litter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctree%20litter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoil%20litter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduff%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cplant%20litter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clitterfall%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleaf%20litter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctree%20litter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csoil%20litter%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cduff%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: If you switch the Ngram to "English Fiction" then *duff* is the clear winner.

Comment: This definition for *duff* is labeled "N. America and Scotland".  It seems that, in England, *duff* is a type of boiled pudding.

Comment: Not to mention that *up the duff* is slang for being pregnant, *get off your duff* is slang for getting off your ass, and *duff* is also British for worthless. So, it's not surprising that it would be at the top in the context of the fiction corpus specifically—which I had not realized existed; that's useful.

Comment: @JasonBassford ... and to *duff* someone *up* is slang for to beat them up.

Comment: The word *duff* is unfortunately rather common for a different use, namely *broken, dodgy, failed, inadequate, useless etc.* (specifically, *already broken* when you get it). *Duff battery* is the one I hear most frequently. [presumably derived from the *rotten* meaning]

Comment: Ah, I see @JasonBassford did list *worthless* there already (reading too fast as usual).

Answer (score 3):

That's also called *duff*.

> **Duff:** the partly decayed organic matter on the forest floor. [[M-W]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/duff)

Or *humus*, perhaps?

> **[Humus](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/humus):** Dark earth made of organic material such as decayed leaves and plants.

---

*Detritus* could also be used but it's broader than *duff* and *leaf litter*.

> The term ***detritus*** is broadly defined as any form of non-living organic matter, including different types of plant tissues (leaf litter, dead wood, aquatic macrophytes, algae) animal tissues etc. [[Detritus and decomposition in ecosystem]](https://books.google.com/books?id=togRqaqbGcEC&pg=PA1&dq=%22detritus%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22detritus%22&f=false)

Answer (score 3):

The part of the forest floor that is composed of a decomposing compost of leaves is historically known (at least in England) as **leaf mould**, which, since it begins with an **L**, is most likely the term you were half-remembering.

In general, though, unless you're specifically talking about the rotting stuff, go with **forest floor**, or @decapitated-soul's suggestion of **detritus**.

Comment: _Mould_ somehow seems to be close to "laub" in the lttle cubby-holes of my mind...

Comment: Then that may be the word you were looking for :) https://news.berkeley.edu/2019/08/19/readingbrainmap/

Answer (score 0):

Where there isn't soil in the forests of the Pacific Northwest it's called *muskeg*

> **Muskeg (noun)** A North American swamp or bog consisting of a mixture of water and partly dead vegetation, frequently covered by a layer of sphagnum or other mosses.

Answer (score -1):

There is **mast** which refers to beech nut husks, acorns etc. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/mast) has

> **mast²**
>
> NOUN
> The fruit of beech, oak, chestnut, and other forest trees, especially as food for pigs.

Here is a typical picture of beech mast.

[image]

<sub>Alamy stock photo</sub>